# I am going to get my car battery replaced or I am going to get battery of my car replaced?

Tags: syntactic-analysis, semantics

Which of these is correct?

> I am going to get my car battery replaced.

OR

> I am going to get the battery of my car replaced.

Comment: Actually, both lack a subject.

Comment: This has been done a lot here.

Answer (score 2):

Car battery.

In English, anything that belongs to the car is called "car" something. Car door, car keys, car bonnet, etc.

I teach ESOL, and notice that a lot of non native speakers of English say and write things like "my car's door" or "the door of my car", which are logical, but not what we say.

Comment: I just replaced the battery in my phone.  Now I'm going to get the battery of my car replaced.

Comment: A "car battery" specifies a type of battery used in a car, it doesn't necessarily _belong_ to a car. For example, I could own a car battery without owning a car (and use it to power something else). So the form used in the second sentence, "[I'm] going to get the battery of my car replaced", actually identifies that I'm replacing the battery that is in my car not just any car battery that I might own.

Comment: I'm a native English speaker. I agree about "car door", but I don't think that principle applies to all parts of the car: I would say "my car's engine" not "my car engine".

Comment: @nnnnnn That's true, but you can often see car engines lying around in scrap yards when they have been removed from cars. The term distinguishes them from motorbike engines, lorry (or truck) engines, bus engines and aero engines. Similarly car batteries are different from motorbike batteries, phone batteries, torch batteries etc.

Comment: @BoldBen - Good point. The phrasing I'd choose depends on context. In some contexts I'd just say "battery" or "engine" and not explicitly mention the car or torch.

Comment: @BoldBen A *car engine* is any engine designed to be part of a car.  *My car's engine* is the specific engine in my car.

Comment: @AntonSherwood I tend to agree with you, however the engine is a much more fundamental part of the car than the battery, under some circumstances it might be a good idea to have two car batteries which are used alternately with the one off the car being charged from the mains. Changing a car battery is much easier than changing an engine. I think that's why we often say "I need a new car battery" when we would not say "I need a new car engine"

Comment: @BoldBen That's orthogonal to my point.  Whether engine or battery or door or tyre or radio or windowshade, I would say “a car [part]” but “my car's [part]”, not “my car [part]”.  Maybe you agree with that, I cannot tell.

Comment: @AntonSherwood I think there might be a difference between US and British practice. The use of "I need a new car battery" is very common in the UK.

Comment: @BoldBen We rebellious colonials say that too, so I don't know what point you're making.

Comment: @AntonSherwood We would also say "My car battery needs changing" in preference to "My car's battery needs changing" which you said you would use.

Answer (score 0):

Personally:  "I'm going to get a replacement battery for my car [tomorrow]." or

"I'm going to get a battery for the car." - This assumes the person you are speaking with already knows you have a car - "the car", as opposed to "my car", if the person may not know about your car.

"The battery of my car" is not a commonly used construct in english and is most likely the result of a literal translation from another language, most often heard from german native speakers.